# element.querySelector vs parentNode.firstElementChild and their synchronicity

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, dom-manipulation, selectors-api

My test case is as follows:

My script is supposed to change appearance of the Clients NavBar. Client adds my script to their html. They supposed to add it at the top to help avoid flicker effect, but sometimes they don't put it at the very top. so the html looks something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <theirScript1/>
    <myScript/>
    <theirScript2/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <theirScript3/>
    <NavBarContainer/>
    <theirScript4/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now let's say that one of thierScripts (I don't know which one) will add NavBar to NavBarContainer. myScript uses intervals to continuously traverse the dom(with document.querySelector) looking for that NavBar. Once I find that element I apply my changes and all is well. My question is in 2 parts.

First: If the whole NavBar including all its children is added by the same theirScript(no matter which one), can I safely look for its children with element.firstElementChild in myScript? Or is it possible that the children would not have been mounted at that time?

So consider the following example for myScript:

```
  //getElement = async function that uses intervals to look for elements matching the selector(can't post for legal reasons)

  const navBarEl = await getElement(selector); // get navBar with intervals

  const navBarFirstChildEl = navBarEl.firstElementChild; // once we get navBarEl element, get its first child without intervals
```

Am I safe using navBarFirstChildEl here? From my understanding the only way this would fail is if navBarEl and navBarFirstChildEl are mounted by different theirScripts. Is this correct?

Second Question: does it make any difference in either scenarios if I use:

```
  const navBarFirstChildEl = filterBar.quertySelector('element:first-child')
```

I know this is long, wordy and confusing question. I really appreciate all of your time and help.

Comment: Please... one question at a time?

Comment: I think both functions are synchronous so whether it’s safe to access children will depend on when they get added and when your code runs.

Comment: they are very very related I think, but if another person upvotes this I will remove the second one